# Convert unsigned char array to NSData and back

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdata, arrays

How do you convert an unsigned char array to an NSData in objective c?

This is what I am trying to do, but it doesn't work.
Buffer is my unsigned char array.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:message length:length];
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can just use this NSData class method

```
+ (id)dataWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length
```

Something like

```
NSUInteger size = // some size
unsigned char array[size];
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)array length:sizeof(unsigned char)*size];
```

You can then get the array back like this (if you know that it is the right data type)

```
NSUInteger size = [data length] / sizeof(unsigned char);
unsigned char* array = (unsigned char*) [data bytes];
```

Comment: When i want to get the array back, does this really work? I cant see you assigning the array to something?

Comment: It's assigned, on the last line. But `[NSData bytes]` gives untyped results, so it needs to be cast to the type you're looking after.

Comment: The first section actually copies the unsigned chars into the NSData (if you don't want that you can use `+ (id)dataWithBytesNoCopy:(void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length` instead), the second just gets a pointer to that data, it does not copy it back.

Comment: Should the last line not be: unsigned char* array = (unsigned char*) [data bytes]; ? It had me puzzled for a min

Comment: @MarkRamotowski well spotted, I don't know it escaped the attention of everyone for over 2 years... Rectified now.